# Twitter bootstrap: Is it possible to center container-fluid with two rows with span5 or span4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap

I have something like this [image]

I have these in a row-fluid with span6. However, I when I do span5 on both of them, they float off the left side, leaving a lot of white space on right free. Can I center them on page ?

Comment: If you use span5 on both elements, then you have space on right side for span2. Try to create one div with span1 before and one after the two divs with span5.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović: That's a good solution. You should post it as an answer so it can be accepted/upgraded

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel, posted as an answer.

Comment: @devcoder, i'm working on some bootstrap project, so i know how many problems you might have :) I'm glad that I helped.

Comment: And I apologize for my bad English :)

Comment: @MiljanPuzović gave a good solution, but if you use a _default_ bootstrap, you could also try those [fluid offsets](https://gist.github.com/3230479).

Comment: @Sherbrow, as I said below, you can theoretically use .offset classes, but they don't work in latest version of Bootstrap.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović Some adjustments made, and it is now [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/LqmSz/) [fluid offsets gist](https://gist.github.com/3230479)

Comment: Nice fix for .offset classes, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `.offset` classes don't work in Bootstrap v2.0.4, you can use `.span1` classes to create empty space on left and on right side around those two elements. Like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span1">
    <!-- empty -->
  </div>
  <div class="span5">
    <!-- content of left element (tree map) -->
  </div>
  <div class="span5">
    <!-- content of right element (datatables) -->
  </div>
  <div class="span1">
    <!-- empty -->
  </div>
</div>
```